# Jquery - page looping when adding a query string to the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a query string to a URL, and it seems to be forcing the page to loop in a constant load. While the page itself does not appear to refresh. Inspecting the code and looking at the browser it seems to be ongoing load (even though the page is rendered and remains rendered). The load when inspecting seems to be a continuous loop from what I can see.

Here is the code that I am using that is causing this. Could anyone help me put something in the code that might make it stop the page load?

```js
if (!window.location.search.trim().length) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '?orderby=1';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to be ongoing load"? What do you see to suggest this?

Comment: Looking at the browser chrome - 2 things. The first at the top in the tab, when your loading a site you will see the loader in the top of the tab (circle) animated gif left side of the active tab. This continues to spin rather than show the Favicon of the site.

The other item is that when you inspect the page, there are some javascript errors I.E.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of null. These continue to load.

Comment: OK, but what makes you think that has anything to do with jQuery or JS in general - couldn't it be some of your images are hanging? You need a clearer debugging route to establish the problem really is JS. Put some `console.log()`'s in to see if some piece of code is repeatedly being hit/loaded.

Comment: The reason I am pinning it on JS is because this was the only code change in recent times.... that I am aware of...

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for the backend to say if orderby is missing, than set it to one instead of causing the page to have to load two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add or update query string parameter:

```
window.location.search = 'orderby=1';
```